# Chrome untrusted certificates

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, ssl

i've ubuntu 14.04 and chrome browser. My https connection is aborted for several website like google.com, youtube.com etc. Other websites works properly. I googled this and supposed that "bogus global trustee" CA is revoked. Can u advice how to fix it and install valid global CA?

For example on google.com page it says:
There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM).

SHA-1 Certificate
The certificate chain for this site contains a certificate signed using SHA-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sudo apt-get install libnss3-1d

This will probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to overcome this problem is add the URL(which encounters this error) in "Add Exception" this column will be displayed under the error-(net::ERR_CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM). so that you can access the web pages without any issues.

Comment: the last chrome version version does not allow to add exception. At the moment I run with --ignore-certificate-errors. But I would like to fix cause.

Comment: did you tried by re-installing chrome?

Comment: yeap, I've reinstalled chrome, updated root certificates by sudo update-ca-certificates. No effect. Also, I've opera browser with the same issue.

Comment: Hope it will work for you....      sudo apt-get install libnss3-1d